# for loop not functioning properly

Tags: c, linux

I'm using c on a Linux Gentoo machine, kernel 4.0.5.

In the for loop (`for c=5`), the loop does not increment correctly, I get the following output:

```
character 5: 1
character 1: e
```

instead of :

```
character 5: 1
character 6: 2 
character 7: 3
```

I cannot figure out why after the first iteration `c` has the value of `1`.

Here's my code:

```
readconfig(FILE * config,GtkComboBoxText * combo)
{
  char line[256];
  char entry[]="";
  int c;
  int current_line;
  int no_of_sets=0;
  int number_of_lines=getlines(config);
  printf("number of lines is: %i\n",number_of_lines);
  while (fgets(line, sizeof line, config) != NULL)
//  for (current_line=0;current_line<number_of_lines;current_line++)
  {
//    fgets(line,sizeof line,config);
    printf("line contents are: %s\n",line);
    if (strncmp(line , "set ", 4)==0)
    {
      printf("hello\n");
      no_of_sets = no_of_sets++;
      for (c=5;c<255;c++)
      {
        if (line[c]=='\0'|| line[c]=='\n' || line[c]=='"' || line[c]==' ')
          break;
        printf("character %i: %c\n",c,line[c]);
        append(entry,line[c]);
      };
      printf("the value of entry is %s\n",entry);
      gtk_combo_box_text_append_text(combo,entry);
      memset(&entry[0], 0, sizeof(entry));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This `char entry[]="";` looks highly suspicious.

Comment: You should have tested the text-manipulation code before mating it to the file-reading code.

Comment: perfect, that fixed it, thanks alot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something is changing the value of c between iterations.  There are no assignments and only printf() takes it as a parameter, so it is done by a memory allocation error.

Most likely append(entry, line[c]) writes into entry[]="", a zero-terminated string which the compiler may be allocating in memory right before int c if for some reason it's not putting c in a register.  So the write to append to the char* entry is writing line[c] into memory where c is, overwriting it.

Test in a debugger or try changing your allocation of entry.

Comment: Most importantly, not only is `entry` a zero-terminated string, but as a `char` array it has length 1.  That is, `sizeof(entry) == 1`.